# PrimeNG chart js is not rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, primeng

I have an issue with displaying chart-js in my angular component:
the chart of type bar is not showing and I have this as html render:

```
<div _ngcontent-tkd-c175="" class="p-col-6">
   <p-chart _ngcontent-tkd-c175="" type="bar">
</p-chart></div>
```

My module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {KpisComponent} from './kpis.component';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ChartModule
} from 'primeng/chart';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ButtonModule} from "primeng/button";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [KpisComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ChartModule,
    ButtonModule
  ]
})
export class KpisModule { }
```

My component's html:

```
<div class="p-col-6">
      <p-chart #chart type="bar" [data]="dataSource"></p-chart>
  </div>

<button type="button" pButton (click)="update($event)" >Update</button>
```

My component ts

```
import {UIChart} from "primeng/chart";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-kpis',
  templateUrl: './kpis.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kpis.component.scss']
})
export class KpisComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('chart') chart: UIChart;
    public dataSource = {} as any;
    public options: any;
  constructor(
    private kpisService: KpisService
  ) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.options = {
          title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'My Title',
              fontSize: 16
          },
          legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
          }
      };

  }



    update($event: MouseEvent) {
        this.dataSource = {
            labels: ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Company1",
                data: [25, 30, 60, 50, 80, 90]
            },
                {
                    label: "Company2",
                    data: [45, 33, 70, 72, 95]
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

My package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",

    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",

    "classlist.js": "~1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "~2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "primeflex": "^1.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",

    "primeng": "^11.3.1"
...
}
```

I added the script in angular.json:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
    ...
            "scripts": [
             "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"
            ],
    ...
```

But I have nothing rendered in the component when I click on the update button.

Did I miss something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code missed passing a basic options object ... Have a look at the examples here --> https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart/bar

Comment: also  you might need to re render the chart after updating the data

Comment: As I can see here, the options is not required: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v11-lts/#/chart

Comment: I tried this setTimeout(() => { this.chart.refresh(); }, 100); at the end of the update function but I have this error: ERROR TypeError: _this.chart.refresh is not a function

Comment: "In order to chart to redraw itself, a new data object needs to be created. Changing the array contents without creating a new array instance does not trigger change detection." Basically what you are doing, you are mutating your array. Create a new instance of your array via spread operation or other means.

Comment: which array you mean? I am creating a new instance of data inside update method:
this.dataSource = {
            labels: ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
....

Comment: I noticed that the chart component works fine on the app Module but not on my new creatd module KpisModule

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not in chartjs or PrimeNG but the module that contains the chart component is not imported in the app Module,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
    imports: [
        ...
        KpisModule   <-- here
    ],
 ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {...
```

Adding it has fixed my issue.